# Why can't we pass ArrayList<Integer> to a method with (Integer...) parameter?

Tags: java, arraylist, variadic-functions

I'm trying to do this Java How To Program Task: "Write an appliaction that calculates the product 
of a series of integers that are passed to method 'product' using a variable-length argument list.

I get the error message that the method product(Integer...) in the type VarLenArgumentList is not applicable for
the arguments (ArrayList). Why so, if Java treats the variable-length argument list as an array? Isn't an ArrayList an array?

What is another way of completing the task?

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int flag = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<>();

do
{
    System.out.print("Enter a positive integer or '-1' to quit:" );
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();
    intArray.add(input);

} while (flag != -1);

product(intArray); 
}

public static int product (Integer... numbers) 
{
    int total = 0;

    for (Integer element : numbers)
        total *= element;

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Nope, this is not a dupe, at least not for the linked question. THe question here is mainly `Isn't an ArrayList an array?`, which is NOT the question in the linked thread.

Comment: In the example you posted `} while (flag == -1);` should be `} while (input != -1)` to match your print condition also `System.out.printf` should require a `String format` argument, which I don't see in your example, so I'm guessing you meant `System.out.print` or `System.out.println`.

Comment: You're right, of course. I've edited my post and improved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integer...` parameter  accepts arbitrary number of `Integer` objects, or an array `Integer[]`. Since `ArrayList<Integer>` is not an `Integer[]`, it is not accepted.

`ArrayList` is NOT an array, it is a `Collection`, while array in java is a different object.

You can however use [`toArray(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[])) method to easily turn your `ArrayList` into an array. but note that it will be a DIFFERENT object, and this is useful mainly when you just want to read from the collection, not write to it.

Answer (score 0):

> What is another way of completing the task?

You can pass a List of Integer into the method.

```
 public static int product (List<Integer> integerList) 
    {
    Integer total = 0;

    for (Integer element : integerList)
        total *= element;

    return total;
    }
```

Comment: But this would not complete this requirement:  "using a variable-length argument list".